# Where to find generated servlet class from JSP in Mac

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am unable to find the generated servlet class for a JSP on Mac(after I run my project in eclipse). I have checked in almost all the folders, where should I look up for it?

Comment: In Eclipse, in the project where you wrote that servlet? What are you asking, and what are you looking for exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wrote a jsp but internally that jsp gets converted into a Servlet. I want to know where is that servlet created?

Comment: Answer depends on the server used, the server plugin used, and their configuration.

Comment: AFAIK, in memory only, unless you tell your servlet container to keep the generated files. Which servlet container are you using? Why do you want that servlet code?

Comment: @BalusC
I am using TOMCAT server. I don't know how to check the server plugin and its configuration.

Comment: @JBNizet 

Container is TOMCAT. I want to see how jsp compiles into Java code by the container.

Comment: Read https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html. Make sure keepgenerated is set to true, deploy your war file by dropping it in the webapps folder, and the files, AFAIR, should be generated somewhere under the work folder.

Comment: I checked the main web.xml and keepGenerated is set to true. So, this part is good. 

1) I don't understand what AFAIR is? 
2) Deploy your war by dropping it in the webapps folder? What does this mean?

I am still unable to locate the file.

My work folder is empty. :(

Comment: AFAIR is web slang. It means "As Far As I Remember". "Deploy your war by dropping it in the webapps folder" means just that: a Java EE web appllication is a war file. To deploy it in tomcat, you just need to copy and paste it into the tomcat webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

Run command in terminal `find ~/ -type f -name YourFile.ext` to look for a file somewhere inside your home folder. Or `find / -type f -name YourFile.ext` everywhere on filesystem.